# Mostrar datos al seleccionar una opción en mi DropDown usando C#, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server

mi pregunta va mas destinada a que me pudieran explicar un poco, la forma correcta en poder mandar a llamar los datos respectivos al Id del producto del que selecciono en un dropdown list, me explico

En mi sistema estoy generando pedidos, que es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi registro en mi base de datos seria asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera saber como puedo hacer la acción de que al momento de yo seleccionar en este caso el producto "POLIPROPILENO AUTOADHERIBLE BRILLANTE", en mi input "Pecio" en la columna "Costo unitario" de mi tabla, me muestre el precio "1.85" que es el precio respectivo del producto que yo seleccione en mi base de datos

Como podría empezar a poder realizar esta actividad

Comment: Podrías editar tu preguntan poniendo código en vez de imágenes

Comment: Las imágenes están bien para poder ver y apreciar que es lo que deseas lograr, pero también publica el código de como estas listando tus artículos y que se llama el input que deseas editar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un excelente momento para aprender Ajax. **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**. La funcionalidad que esperas es uno de sus casos de uso. Básicamente es la transformación del html de forma asíncrona, sin un **postback** (sin re cargar la página web desde el servidor).

Los pasos que debes seguir, son los siguientes:

1-. Debe existir una función en tu javascript que capture el evento de cambio del dropdown, 'onChange'. Este evento deberá capturar el ID de base de datos del producto que escojas.

2-. Con el id en mano, mediante AJAX puedes hacer una petición al [WebMethod] si es aspx, un método del Controller si es MVC, etc., para que desde tu código puedas hacer el llamado a la base de datos mediante linq, query preparada, procedimiento almacenado, etc.

3-. Una vez obtengas el precio del ítem, dentro de la petición ajax puedes obtener el objeto donde muestras el precio y reemplazar su valor.

No tenemos mucha información acerca de tu estructura, código, etc., pero con este checklist tienes cómo empezar.

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte, es justo como lo estoy haciendo con MVC!!